# Problem with Anaconda installation

Tags: windows, python, installation

This is what comes up any time I start up Anaconda Prompt -

```
\Xtralien was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\User Name>            @SET "PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\QuantumWise\VNL-ATK-2016.3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelSGXPSW\bin\x64\Release\;C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelSGXPSW\bin\win32\Release\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.1\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuantumWise\VNL-ATK-2016.3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelSGXPSW\bin\x64\Release\;C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelSGXPSW\bin\win32\Release\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.1\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xtralien Python Distribution\Scripts";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xtralien Python Distribution";c:\FullProf_Suite"
C:\Users\User Name>
```

I am guessing it's because of a conflict with an [old Xtralien python installation](https://www.ossila.com/pages/xtralien-scientific-python) that I had and forgot about. I uninstalled that and reinstalled Anaconda but it hasn't resolved the problem.

Comment: How are you installing Anaconda?

Comment: I am installing it with the Anaconda 5.0.1 Windows Installer from here - https://www.anaconda.com/download/
 with all the default options besides the directory which I switched to a folder in E drive. So - Installing it for 'just me' and registering anaconda as the default for Python

Comment: Have you tried switching to the drive Anaconda is installed on?

Comment: That and installing it in C drive itself too

Comment: Whenever I see an "unexpected at this time" error it's in my batch scripts, and it's either because I didn't use the correct escape character, or an absolute path is incorrect. I don't see Anaconda anywhere in your PATH, but I do see Xtralien. Is it possible that you need to add Anaconda?

Comment: Not changing the default directory and adding it my path variable during the installation seems to have done the trick. Thanks a bunch for the advice!

Comment: Cool I'll add an answer explain what's happening. Feel free to accept :)

Comment: Please add this comment as an answer so this Q&A will not appear anymore in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 2):

@PrestonM indicated that:

> Whenever I see an "unexpected at this time" error it's in my batch
>   scripts, and it's either because I didn't use the correct escape
>   character, or an absolute path is incorrect. I don't see Anaconda
>   anywhere in your PATH, but I do see Xtralien. Is it possible that you
>   need to add Anaconda?

OP feedback was:

> Not changing the default directory and adding it my path variable
>   during the installation seems to have done the trick. Thanks a bunch
>   for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

We recommend not adding Anaconda to the PATH environment variable, since this can interfere with other software [read more ...](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows)

Anaconda 4.4 added a feature to the Windows installer so that the “verbose” install information is printed out to a special debug streame [read more ...](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting#i-m-having-trouble-with-the-anaconda-installer-on-windows-how-can-i-debug-my-issue)